# Git pre-push hook doesn't seem to be working with git push

Tags: git, githooks

I am on my testbranch:

```
$git branch
  master
* testbranch
```

Here is my code in `.git/hooks/pre-push` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
protected_branch='testbranch'
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $protected_branch = $current_branch ]
    then
            echo "Test"
            pwdlsfail

            rc=$?
            if [[ $rc != 0 ]] ; then
                echo "test failed - push denied. Run tests locally and confirm they pass before pushing"
                exit $rc
            fi
else
# Everything went OK so we can exit with a zero
    exit 0
fi
```

Tried running above code as a shell script and works fine:

```
$./1.sh  
Test
./1.sh: line 8: pwdlsfail: command not found
test failed on rev  - push denied. Run tests locally and confirm they pass before pushing
```

But `pre-push` hook is still not getting called with `git push origin testbranch`, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds from your description that you're trying to put the `pre-receive` hook into your local repository. That's not how it works - the `pre-receive` hook should be on your remote. If you want to run something locally before you push, use the `pre-push` hook.

There are several other hooks listed in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) that you may also find useful.

Comment: Will it work if I rename pre-receive to pre-push if I want it locally?

Comment: If whatever you're trying to do in the script makes sense in that context, yes.

Comment: I moved pre-receive to pre-push but that also dint work. Am I missing something?

Comment: A `pre-push` commit hook doesn't take the same arguments or input as a `pre-receive` hook, so the hook you've shown won't work, no. You need to modify it to behave differently.

Comment: Let me find out an example for pre-push to do the exact same thing and get back on this question. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation (linked in my answer) has all of the details regarding the input and the arguments passed to the script. Just throw a single echo statement in and you'll see it run.

Comment: I am very new to this, so I won't be able to do this test quickly, need some time.

Comment: I upgraded git version and can run it now, thanks everyone!